# UITableView can be scrolled too far top after adding UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

After I've added `UISearchController` to the `UITableView` using the code below.

```
lazy var searchCardController: SearchCardController = {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchCard") as? SearchCardController
}()!

lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
    return UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchCardController)
}()

//Core Data
lazy var stack: CoreDataStack = {
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return delegate.stack
}()

lazy var dataSource: CardCategoryDataSource = {
    // Create a fetchrequest
    let fr = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CD_CardCategory")
    fr.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

    // Create the FetchedResultsController
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fr, managedObjectContext: stack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return CardCategoryDataSource(fetchedResultsController: fetchedResultsController!)
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = dataSource

    setupSearchBar()
}

func setupSearchBar() {

    searchController.searchBar.delegate = searchCardController
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchCardController
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

    searchCardController.searchController = searchController

    definesPresentationContext = true

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

}
```

The `UITableView` can be scrolled too far top which is kinda odd as shown in the screenshot below.
[image]

Supposedly the table view should behave like the screenshot below.
[image]

Any help is very much appreciated.

**UPDATED:**
Added GIF to better explain the issue.
[image]

Comment: You need to add a table view header with a height equal to that of the search bar.

Comment: @slickdaddy I tried to alter the table view header just like what you have advised but the issue is still there. The weird thing is that the issue will be fixed by itself every time I click on the Search Bar and followed by the Cancel search bar button.

Comment: I ran into a similar one on iOS11. I moved the calculation of the height of cells to the delegate func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath), and in the viewDidLoad set: 
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0, 
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0, 
self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0.

Comment: @Harman The problem is fixed after I added self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150. Thanks for giving me the idea! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed after I defined the `estimatedRowHeight` to the exact row height that I wanted as shown below in `viewDidLoad`.

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
```

Special thanks to @Harman for giving me the idea.